# how to use Bootstrap-vue in laravel to include pagination to tables

Tags: laravel, pagination, bootstrap-vue

i don't know how to add pagination to tables,to make the pages more cleaner when i have a lot of data to show on tables.

i searched for bootstrap-vue and learned a bit of Vue.js (components ... etc) but seeing this code from : 
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination-nav/

```
    <template>
      <div class="overflow-auto">
      <b-pagination-nav :link-gen="linkGen" :number-of-pages="10" use- router />
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      export default {
        methods: {
          linkGen(pageNum) {
            if (pageNum === 1) {
              return '?'
            } else {
              return '?page=' + pageNum
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

i did not understand what i should do to make this code run on my tables , and make the table pagination work .

this is how the code that is showing the tables in my .blade.php looks :

```
<table class="table" style="border-radius:1em;  border-collapse: collapse; overflow: hidden;">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Id</th>
                    <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
                    <th scope="col">Type_compte</th>
                    <th scope="col">District</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cds</th>
                    <th scope="col">crée a</th>
                    <th scope="col">Verifié</th>
                    <th scope="col">modifier</th>
                    <th scope="col">supprimer</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach($utilisateurs as $utilisateur)
                <tr>
                        <th>{{$utilisateur->id}}</th>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->email}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->Type_compte}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->district == '' ? '/' : $utilisateur->district}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->cds == '' ? '/' : $utilisateur->cds}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->created_at}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->email_verified_at=='' ? 'Non' : 'Oui'}}</td>
                        <form method="GET" action="/comptes/{{$utilisateur->email}}/edit">
                          @csrf
                        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Modifier"></td> 
                        </form>                               
                        <form method="POST" action="/comptes/{{$utilisateur->email}}">
                          @method('DELETE')
                          @csrf
                        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Supprimer"></td> 
                        </form>       
                </tr>
                @endforeach
              </table>
```

what should i do to make table pagination work ? and what is easiest way to do it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why exactly you want to use vue.js for this scenario? I suggest you use the default Laravel's pagination. The documentation explains everything quite well, you can check here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
@foreach($utilisateurs as $utilisateur)
                <tr>
                        <th>{{$utilisateur->id}}</th>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->email}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->Type_compte}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->district == '' ? '/' : $utilisateur->district}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->cds == '' ? '/' : $utilisateur->cds}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->created_at}}</td>
                        <td>{{$utilisateur->email_verified_at=='' ? 'Non' : 'Oui'}}</td>
                        <form method="GET" action="/comptes/{{$utilisateur->email}}/edit">
                          @csrf
                        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Modifier"></td> 
                        </form>                               
                        <form method="POST" action="/comptes/{{$utilisateur->email}}">
                          @method('DELETE')
                          @csrf
                        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Supprimer"></td> 
                        </form>       
                </tr>
                @endforeach

{{ $utilisateurs->links() }}
```

The code **$utilisateurs->links()** will generate your pagination inside the view.

And in the controller, when you pass the data to the view you use **paginate(numOfRecordsPerPage)** something like this **$users = App\User::paginate(15);** where **User** is the model you are accessing.

Otherwise, if you still want to use vue.js for this, or in other words, to make the page dynamic and not reload every time you click on the pagination, then you should set up an API endpoint where you get the data and then you need to use Vue again to list the records in your table.

Comment: thank you very much my friend i actually found this in the internet just after posting my question :) , i can confirm it works .